# Restrict Windows shell extension to folder/drive

Tags: windows, windows-shell, shell-extensions

I'm working on a shell extension that is supposed to display extended properties of files (mostly .jpgs) stored on a virtual drive (think of it as an external harddrive).

Is it possible to register the shell extension in a way that it only kicks in for files of a specific folder/drive (in my case the external harddrive) and leaves the handling of jpgs in other folder to the Windows default shell extension?

Regards,

Sebastian

Answer (score 1):

This article lists ways that you can register your shell extension: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144096(VS.85).aspx.

You should be able to create a system folder on your external harddrive that contains a desktop.ini file that points to your extension.

Alternately, within the extension itself you could check the path and not do the extra logic if it's not located in your designated spot.

Answer (score 0):

Place Your app infos in:
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\